# Java 1.8 161+ jjs, cannot run using windows classpath

Tags: java, windows, classpath, jjs

Trying to run jjs on windows using jdk1.8.0_171:

```
D:\Java\64\jre1.8.0_171\bin\jjs.exe -cp "d:\dev\gitrepos\lconfig\target\classes;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.4\jackson-core-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.4\jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-afterburner\2.9.4\jackson-module-afterburner-2.9.4.jar" -scripting \dev\gitrepos\lconfig/src/test/js/react-renderer/test.js 
::D:\Java\64\jre1.8.0_171\bin\jjs.exe -cp "\dev\gitrepos\lconfig\target\classes;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.4.jar;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.4\jackson-core-2.9.4.jar;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.4\jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.4.jar;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.4.jar;\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-afterburner\2.9.4\jackson-module-afterburner-2.9.4.jar" -scripting \dev\gitrepos\lconfig/src/test/js/react-renderer/test.js
```

If I have d: within the path, then it fails with:

```
jjs [<options>] <files> [-- <arguments>]
"Illegal char <:> at index 40: d:\dev\gitrepos\lconfig\target\classes;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.4.jar;<SNIPPED>;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-afterburner\2.9.4\jackson-module-afterburner-2.9.4.jar" is not a recognized option. Use "-h" or "-help" to see a list of all supported options.
```

If I run the command without d: in the path it runs fine

Ultimately though I need to use the d: because my real problem is that I am trying to exec this in maven using

```
jjs -cp %classpath ...
```

Across the team here we have people where the maven exec is working perfectly well, and others with same problem as me, we cannot see any difference between those where it works and those where it doesn't.
Stumped, anyone know why the : is breaking this?

Update:
If I run with _91 then all works fine:

```
D:\Java\64\jre1.8.0_91\bin\jjs.exe -cp "d:\dev\gitrepos\lconfig\target\classes;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.4\jackson-core-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.4\jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.4.jar;d:\dev\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-afterburner\2.9.4\jackson-module-afterburner-2.9.4.jar" -scripting \dev\gitrepos\lconfig/src/test/js/react-renderer/test.js
Loading renderer...
Loading manifest to locate bundle...
Loading bundle ./src/main/app/build/static/js/main.b12d3fdf.js ...
Success!
```

Comment: being tracked as: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8203853

Comment: Closed as "Won't Fix" too. :(